# Import CSV data to C++ structure

Tags: c++, csv

Import the data from a comma separated file to a struct in C++

eg: CSV file:

```
1,2,3,"Data"
11,12,13,"Data2"
```

I am supposed to import this data to my struct.

```
struct data
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char *ch;
};
```

I need to write a C++ program to import the data from CSV file to this structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the following topics:

1. Standard strings ([std::string class](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)).
2. I/O and standard streams ([std::ifstream class](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/)).

After that, it will be a piece of cake to implement the program.

Comment: `istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim )`  would also help. But the most important part for a beginner is part of what you said: to use std::string instead of char*...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`scanf()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).